# Knapsack 1/0 bottom up approach

Tags: algorithm

Hi all i have just started out dynamic programming in my sch and am facing some issue with my code but cant seem to find the error hope that somebody can find it.

I have initialized the first col and first row of the total_profit to be = 0 before putting into the parameter.

```
//bottom up approach
//n is number of objects
void knapsack(int* weights, int* profits, int capacity, int n, int total_profit[capacity + 1][n + 1]) {
    for(int r = 1; r< capacity+1; r++){
        for(int c = 1; c< n+1; c++){
            total_profit[r][c] = total_profit[r][c-1];
            if (weights[c-1] <= r){
                    if(total_profit[r][c] < total_profit[r-weights[r-1]][c-1] + profits[c-1]){
                        total_profit[r][c] = total_profit[r][c-1] + profits[c-1];
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: has anybody ever made an acceptable answer to your questions?